# A German equivalent for "The devil's in detail"

Tags: idiom

I want a German equivalent for "The devil's in detail", Which literally means:

> "This plan sounds simple when you describe what needs to be done at a high level, but actually doing it will be very difficult when it comes to the details"

For instance, when you're told that minor details are not important, you'd use the idiom to say it's not so, Details are important and not considering them will affect the whole problem.

Update: I don't need literal translations of the English idiom, I can find them in dictionaries. I want to know what do Germans say in such situations.

---

<sup>[See the question in English Language and Usage for more information](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60956/asking-for-an-idiom-according-to-literal-translation)</sup>

Comment: simple translation request, can be found in dict.leo.org

Comment: @Takkat Der Close-Vote ist übrigens von mir. Ich stimme userunknown zu. Die ursprüngliche Frage war ganz einfach mit Dictionary zu lösen, und nachdem das Update eingefügt wurde, hat sich auch nichts wesentliches geändert. Das erkennt man daran, dass JohnSmithers keine wesentliche Änderung machen musste um seine Antwort nicht off-topic werden zu lassen.

Comment: @Takkat: Oh come on. The whole premise is flawed. Dictionaries *do* list appropriate idioms instead of literal translations. Just look for example for "to be all fingers and thumbs". It's translated as "zwei linke Hände haben" in leo and dict.cc. That's miles from the literal translation. A simple Google search confirms that it's in wide use. There was clearly zero research done before asking the question (cf. http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/355/hey-is-this-general-reference). If you think this site makes no sense like this, we might as well have no restrictions at all.

Comment: @Takkat: As musiKk pointed out, user508 searched for a translation of the idiom, and told us, that she is able to translate it word by word with a dictionary, but the dictionary provides a translation of the idiom, which just happens to be a nearly word by word translation. `Stecken` isn't a simple translation for `in`.

Comment: @Em1: not a real question? >It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form - Da bin ich ja froh, dass ich es dennoch geschafft habe, sie zu benantworten :)

Comment: Isn't the *correct* English idiom "The devil's in *the* details"?  Google... yup, Google and the rest of the world seem to agree with my recollection.

Answer (score 41):

> Der Teufel steckt im Detail.

The German idiom is almost a literal translation of the English phrase.

Comment: As you see, I'm looking for common German idioms not the literal translation of that.

Comment: @Gigili [It is common](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=teufel+steckt+im+detail&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=de&client=opera&hs=EK&rls=de&channel=suggest&source=hp&q=teufel+steckt+im+detail&oq=teufel+steckt+im+detail+wiki&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=2&gs_upl=0l0l0l56545l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&gs_l=serp.2...0l0l0l56545l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5945ae8e2ef9a5a0&biw=1920&bih=860)

Comment: @Gigili: It's not only common, it is _the_ German idiom for this situation.

Comment: BTW, there is a common extension "... und im Restalkohol!"

Comment: Isn't the English phrase a literal translation of the German idiom?  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a more regional translation: I heard some people from around Stuttgart say

> "Der Teufel isch a Eichhörnle."

(The devil is a sqirrel).

Comment: Das gibt's auch auf Hochdeutsch: "Der Teufel ist ein Eichhörnchen".

Comment: But that's *not the same meaning* - "D'r Deifl isch a Eichhörnle" heißt dass Dinge schnell schiefgehen können, wenn man nicht gut/sorgfältig achtgibt.

Comment: @Stephie Das ist doch genau die Bedeutung. Wo soll der Unterschied sein?

Comment: @Sentry: Das ist meines Erachtens auch etwas völlig Anderes. "Der Teufel ist ein Eichhörnchen" kenne ich zumindest nur in der Bedeutung, dass kritische Schwierigkeiten plötzlich und völlig unerwartet auftauchen können (eben genau wie kleine, herumhuschende Eichhörnchen). Die Redewendung bezieht sich auf ein mögliches *Scheitern*. "Der Teufel steckt im Detail" bringt dagegen selten das Gesamtvorhaben in Gefahr, sondern bezieht sich vielmehr auf signifikante Aufwände für kleine Details, die in keinem Verhältnis zur angenommenen Bedeutung des Detailaspekts am Gesamtwerk stehen.